# How to hook the abstract method getUserAgentString?

Tags: android, subclass, abstract, xposed

I want to hook WebSettings's `getUserAgentString` system method. But this method is abstract. In fact, WebSettings itself is an abstract class. Hooking the method gives the following exception.

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot hook abstract methods: public abstract java.lang.String android.webkit.WebSettings.getUserAgentString()`

Usually we call `new WebView(this).getSettings().getUserAgentString()`, but I never know what the implementing subclass is. So what can I do in this case?

Comment: I have not tried it but it may be possible to hook the default constructor of `WebSettings` and therefore detect when a subclass instance is created (as it should call this constructor). Then you would get all classes that implement `WebSettings` and that are used so you could hook the actual WebSettings implementation.

Comment: you have solution yet to hook user-agent string for webview